# React typescript - Parsing error: Unexpected token - after upgrading to 17.0.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, upgrade

After upgrading to

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1"
```

All my types (or Interface) are not recognized anymore. It was working fine with React `"react": "16.13.1"`

Example with this error:

```
  Line 18:3:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  16 | type Props = {
  17 |   onCancel: () => void
> 18 |   text: string
     |   ^
  19 |   userRoleCompanie: UserRoleCompanie
  20 | }
  21 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you probably figured it out already, but for the future generations: You have to delete the .eslintrc file from the root of the project.